# firebase game where each player has a target

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm trying to develop a game where in 1 of the rounds, the players each have a different player as their target.

Here's my logic: I do a .onSnapshot() on my players collection to get my data in real-time.

then for each player, I do a Math.floor(Math.random()*players.length) to get a random target for my player. Then I do a check:

Does the player have themselves as their target or is it already someone's target?
=> find new target

else assign target to the player. (also set the target's isATarget to true in firebase)
repeat for all other players.

Now I have 2 issues with this approach:

if there are 4 players (a, b, c, d) then it's possible that a has b, b has c, c has a, and d will never find a target, causing to loop a function forever.

another problem I have is that my player array doesn't update in real-time. So the code is unable to detect when someone's isATarget is set to true.

here's my source code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { useLocation } from "react-router"
import { db } from "../../services/firestore"

const Round2Info = () => {

    const [players, setPlayers] = useState([]);
    const [foundPlayers, setFoundPlayers] = useState(false)
    const location = useLocation();
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (location.state.you.host === true) { // so only 1 person in the lobby is executing this code
            console.log('Step 1: code is only accessable by host');
            // get players
            db.collection("GameLobbies").doc(location.state.lobby.id).collection("players").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
                let playersArr = players;
                console.log('getting players in round2info');
                const changes = snapshot.docChanges();
                changes.forEach(change => {
                    if (change.type === 'added') {
                        playersArr.push(change.doc.data());
                    }
                })
                setPlayers([...playersArr]);
                setFoundPlayers(true);
            });

        }
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(foundPlayers){
            console.log('foundPlayers is true so', players); // this works. it shows all players
            givePlayersTheirTarget();
        }

    },[foundPlayers])

    const givePlayersTheirTarget = () => {
            console.log('Step 2: every player,', players, 'foreach'); // works
            players.forEach(player => {
                givePlayerTheirTarget(player)
            })
    }

    const givePlayerTheirTarget = player => {
        console.log('Step 3: player get their target');
        let target = getRandomPlayer();
        if (target.id === player.id || target.isATarget === true) {
            console.log(player.name, 'cant have', target.name, 'as their target');
            givePlayerTheirTarget(player);
        } else {
            console.log(player.name, 'has', target.name, 'as their target');
            // set target's isATarget to true
            db.collection("GameLobbies").doc(location.state.lobby.id).collection("players").doc(target.id).update({
                isATarget: true
            });
            // assign target to person
            db.collection("GameLobbies").doc(location.state.lobby.id).collection("players").doc(player.id).update({
                round2Target: target.name
            })
            console.log(players); // player who's been picked as a target stills shows isATarget = false while it should be true by now
        }
    }

    const getRandomPlayer = () => {
        return players[Math.floor(Math.random() * players.length)];
    }

    return (
        <div className="container">
            round 2 info
        </div>
    )
}
export default Round2Info
```

Answer (score 0):

About first issue: you can make algorithm to prefer targeting player that are not involved yet -> targeting players who don't have any target set, this will make player-C targeting player-D instead of player-A/ Player A is already involved in gameplay (even if only as a "hunter", not "prey"), so better decision will be to add player-D. When all players have their "target" set then you can just select the nearest player